# how fix Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-typescript

Trying out TypeScript for a React project and I'm stuck on this error.

> TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ paymentMethod: string; amount: string; receiptCode: string; paymentDate: string; paymentSourceID: string; }'.   No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ paymentMethod: string; amount: string; receiptCode: string; paymentDate: string; paymentSourceID: string; }'

when i try setInputs()

> setInputs(inputs => ({...inputs, [inputs.field[eventName]]: eventValue}));

and this is my component.

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {DatePicker} from "jalali-react-datepicker";
import axios from "axios";
import PaymentFormClasses from './PaymentForm.module.css';
import PaymentCard from "../../Cards/PaymentCard/PaymentCard";
import Card from "../../Cards/Card";

interface PaymentForm {
    field: {
        paymentMethod: string,
        amount: string,
        receiptCode: string,
        paymentDate: string,
        paymentSourceID: string
    }
}

const PaymentForm = () => {
    const [inputs, setInputs] = useState<PaymentForm>({
        field: {
            paymentMethod: '',
            amount: '',
            receiptCode: '',
            paymentDate: '',
            paymentSourceID: 'paymentSourceID'
        }
    });

    const changedHandler = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement> | React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => {
        console.log(typeof e.target.name);
        const eventName = e.target.name;
        const eventValue = e.target.value;

        setInputs(inputs => ({...inputs, [inputs.field[eventName]]: eventValue}));
        console.log(e.target.value);
    }
   

    return (
        <>

        </>
    );
};

export default PaymentForm;
```

Comment: This is a very common issue.  I'm sure this can be closed as a duplicate.  Do `const eventName = e.target.name as keyof PaymentForm['field'];`

Comment: am really confused with your syntax ```{...inputs, [inputs.field[eventName]]: eventValue}``` , i believe it should be something like ```{...inputs, inputs.field[eventName]: eventValue}```

Comment: @pavankumar `inputs.field[eventName]: eventValue` is invalid syntax. It should probably be `{ field: { ...inputs.field, [eventName]:  eventValue } }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assert that `e.target.name`, which is always just `string`, is in fact a valid key of `inputs.field`.

```
const eventName = e.target.name as keyof PaymentForm['field'];
```

However your update syntax is not right.  You are setting top-level properties of inputs and you are using the *value* of `inputs.field[eventName]` as the property name.

You could do a nested update:

```
setInputs(inputs => ({ 
  ...inputs, 
  field: { 
    ...inputs.field, 
    [eventName]: eventValue 
  }
}));
```

But why do we need to have this `field` property at all?  It's the only property in `inputs` so why don't we just make it be the entire state.

```
interface Fields {
  paymentMethod: string;
  amount: string;
  receiptCode: string;
  paymentDate: string;
  paymentSourceID: string;
}

const PaymentForm = () => {
  const [fields, setFields] = useState<Fields>({
    paymentMethod: "",
    amount: "",
    receiptCode: "",
    paymentDate: "",
    paymentSourceID: "paymentSourceID"
  });

  const changedHandler = (
    e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLSelectElement>
  ) => {
    setFields((fields) => ({
      ...fields,
      [e.target.name as keyof Fields]: e.target.value
    }));
  };

  return <></>;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Your eventName can be a union of the field keys. Try this.

```
type EventName = 'paymentMethod' | 'amount' | 'recieptCode' ...etc;
const eventName = e.target.name as EventName; // OR

const eventName = e.target.name as keyof PaymentForm['field'];
```